# Unity character controller preventing movement stacking with W + A/D keys

Tags: unity-game-engine, controller, character

I've been trying to make a really basic fps character controller script, but I couldn't solve the movement stacking when I'm moving sideways. I'm sure it's really basic solutin, but as a beginner it's hard for me to solve it.

```c#
float forwardSpeed = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * movementspeed;
float sideSpeed = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * movementspeed;

Vector3 VecForwardSpeed = new Vector3(sideSpeed, verticalVelocity, forwardSpeed);

VecForwardSpeed = transform.rotation * VecForwardSpeed;

characterController.Move(VecForwardSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly what you mean is if moving forward and sidewards at the same time these inputs/velocities "stack" or sum up allowing the user to move faster then actually allowed.

You could solve this by normalizing them meaning you make sure that combined they never exceed a magnitude value of `1` like e.g.

```c#
// Get a vector of the combined input
var combinedInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));

// Check if the magnitude exceeds 1 
// sqrMagnitude is more efficient here and for comparing to 1
// behaves the same as magnitude
if(combinedInput.sqrMagnitude > 1)
{
   // If so normalize the input vector to force it again
   // to have the maximum length/magnitude of 1
   combinedInput.Normalize();
}
// Until then apply the movementspeed here
combinedInput *= movementspeed;

// Now use the components of this combined and evtl normalized input vector instead
var vecForwardSpeed = transform.rotation * new Vector3(combinedInput.x, verticalVelocity, combinedInput.y) * Time.deltaTime;
characterController.Move(vecForwardSpeed);
```

From your question it is not sure though how the `verticalVelocity` comes into play.

Comment: Yes exactly! Thank you so much for the explanation aswell!